# Delete number phone Contact - Swift 3 - 4

Tags: ios, swift, contacts-framework

I want to delete a contact number, I use **ContactsUI**

```
//only do this to the first contact matching our criteria
   guard let contact = contacts?.first else{
   return
    }
   let editContact = contact.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact

   editContact.phoneNumbers[1]..... ?
```

in  editContact.phoneNumbers[1].. I want to eliminate that number that is in that position

to edit it, I edit it in this way. and it works well

```
editContact.phoneNumbers[1] =  CNLabeledValue(label: "home",
                                                          value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: "1234567"))
```

**but** how do I eliminate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phoneNumbers` is an array. Remove the desired element like you would any other array value:

```
let editContact = contact.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact
editContact.phoneNumbers.remove(at: 1)
```

Of course I'd make sure there are at least 2 phone numbers before doing that.